# как сделать bundle.css файл из нескольких css файлов с postCss?

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix, postcss

Есть проект Laravel, в нем есть соотвественно файл `webpack.mix.js` и содержимое файла такое:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js(['resources/js/app.js', 'resources/js/bootstrap.js'], 'public/js/bundle.js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css/app.css');
```

Здесь видно что метод `js()` принимает два параметра, первый это массив с путями двух `.js` файлов которые являются "входными", второй параметр метода это "выходной" файл который является бандлом этих двух входных, все круто и понятно. Так вот, **как с помощью `mix.postCss()` забандлить так же несколько `.css` файлов?**

*p.s. их документация ведет на github и не очень понятно, что и где .______.*

*p.s. есть `postcss.config.js` (соотвественно есть пакет `laravel-mix-postcss-config`) где подключаются два плагина `cssnano` и `precss`. если это как то поможет*